# Use 'in' or 'out' in layout when create tessellation evaluation shaders?

Tags: opengl, glsl, shader

In `OpenGL Programming Guide`, some code use 'in' in tessellation evaluation shader like this:

```c
layout(triangles,equal_spacing,ccw,points) out;
```

and some times like this:

```c
layout (quads,equal_spacing,cw) in;
```

the name of variables changes,some times it's `out`,some times `in`,I'm confused.And I changed it in my code, there are no differences,so what are the differences between `in` and `out`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> [...] the name of variables changes, some times it's `out`, some times `in`.

No it is not.

The [Tessellation Evaluation Shader](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Tessellation_Evaluation_Shader) allows you to specify input layout qualifiers for the primitive-mode, vertex-spacing, and order.
The  [Tessellation Control Shader](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Tessellation_Control_Shader) allows you to specify the output layout qualifier for the number of vertices.

See [OpenGL Shading Language 4.60 Specification (HTML) - 4.4. Layout Qualifiers](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL/specs/gl/GLSLangSpec.4.60.html#layout-qualifiers)

The layout qualifier:

> ```c
> layout(triangles,equal_spacing,ccw,points) out;
> ```

is incorrect and causes a compile time error.

Comment: Oh,I understand now.Even`layout(triangles,equal_spacing,ccw,points) out;` works fine on my computer,I will write correct codes.Thank you!!!